# How to pass parameter from receiveActivity to another activity?

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation, workflow-activity

Is it possible to pass the parameters of a ReceiveActivity to an Activity in a no-code behind?

I don't want to create a property on the workflow.

I did click on Bind property of the Activity, but it doesn't show the ReceivedActivity parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Try it the other way round. Click on Bind property of the parameter.